# Problem: PHP function argument value used in jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i have a problem with php function arg value (used in jQuery Ajax).

JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#general-settings').submit(function(e) {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'POST',
      url: 'settings.php',
      data: {
        check: 1,
        ...,
      },
      success: function(response) {
        console.log(response);
        if(response == 'redirect') {
          window.location.href='login.php';
        }
      }
    });
    e.preventDefault();
  })
});
```

Php function code:

```
  function isLogged($js_redirect) {
    if(isset($_SESSION['isLogged']) == false) {
      if($js_redirect === true) {
        exit('redirect');
      }
      if($js_redirect === false) {
        exit(header('Location: login.php'));
      }
    }
  }
```

I use this function in:

```
  isLogged(false); // check when you access the page if you are logged in

  // when the submit button is pressed, the following code is executed:
  if(isset($_POST['check'])) {
    isLogged(true); // check when sending, if you are logged in. (here false is executed instead of true.)

    /* ...irrelevant code... */

  }
```

The problem is when you check again if you are logged in. The function is executed with the argument (false) instead of (true) and I don't understand why?

- isLogged(false) is at the beginning of the script and check user.
- isLogged(true) check if you are logged in when you want to save some
  settings. But I don't understand why it takes the value of the
  argument of the first function when it is executed. (false instead of
  true..)

Comment: Is there any reason for having `if($js_redirect === true) {` for both checks?

Comment: @NigelRen the first statement is true the second is false.

Comment: How do you know `$js_redirect` is false where it should be true? Please explain what your error is.

Comment: @Michel I added several explanations in the code. (to the question)

Comment: I can see what is executed, and understand why. What I ask is: HOW do you know it is executed with the wrong value. Have you outputted `$js_redirect` somewhere to check it's value. Because `isLogged()` **always** executes with the value given. So I suspect the logic in your function is flawed or something else is happening that you don't show right now, thus triggering the wrong action.

Comment: @Michel

I checked in the console to find that it is executed with the value "true".
If I remove this block of code from the function:

     ` if($js_redirect === false) {
        exit(header('Location: login.php'));
      }`

Then it is executed with the correct value.

Comment: Try `header('Location: login.php');die;` instead of `exit(header('Location: login.php')); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because of the way you have redacted your code it is hard to know for sure, but it looks like only the first `isLogged(false)` gets called since you `exit` within the `isLogged` function. So this bit:

```php
if(isset($_POST['check'])) {
    isLogged(true); // check when sending, if you are logged in. (here false is executed instead of true.)
    /* ...irrelevant code... */
}
```

never actually gets executed.

Something like this:

```php
// when the submit button is pressed, the following code is executed:
if(isset($_POST['check'])) {
    isLogged(true); // check when sending, if you are logged in. (here false is executed instead of true.)

    /* ...irrelevant code... */
} else {
    isLogged(false); // check when you access the page if you are logged in
}
```

might be what you are looking for

Comment: isLogged(false); is the first line in the script and is executed correctly.
if(isset($_POST['check'])) is executed on interaction with jquery + ajax.

Comment: @andrei_bancos Are these in separate files? Then you should at the very least separate them into different code blocks. Otherwise the `exit` statement inside the `isLogged` function will terminate the script (the entire script not just the function call) and you will never ever reach the isset check.

Comment: Now I've checked in another way. Looks like he wasn't getting to that block of code. (It's harder to tell sometimes). Thanks :)